# Reading a string with fscanf

Tags: c++

I was wondering how I could read a string from a file (called myFile) using fscanf.  I've written this:

```
FILE *myFile;
string name[100];
int grade, t = 0, place = 0;

if (myFile == NULL) {
    cout << "File not found";
    return;
}

while (t != EOF) {
    t = fscanf(myFile, "%s %d\n", &name[place], &grade[place]);
    place++;
}
```

It gives me this error:

Error   C2109   subscript requires array or pointer type on the line with fscanf
I've used iostream and stdio.h

Comment: C IO functions don't know anything about C++ classes (`name`) and `grade` is not an array.

Comment: Use C++ I/O instead.

Comment: What could I use in cpp using only iostream if I want the same effect?

Answer (score 2):

grade is an int and you don't need the index.

```
t = fscanf(myFile, "%s %d\n", &name[place], &grade[place]);
```

should be

```
t = fscanf(myFile, "%s %d\n", &name[place], &grade);
```

Comment: Use char *name[100] then

Comment: oops my bad that should have been grade[100].  Must have made a mistake copying over the code.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, you can use:

```
#include <fstream>
std::ifstream file("myFile.txt");
```

Assuming each line of your file is a string followed by int,as in your code,you can use something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(){
int place =0,grade[5];
std::string name[5];
std::ifstream file("myFile.txt");

while(!file.eof()){ // end of file
 file >>name[place]>>grade[place];
place++;
}
return 0;
//Make sure you check the sizes of the buffers and if there was no error 
//at the opening of the file
}
```